Problem with the ps2pdf creating an animation for the binomial law
I don't why my animation won't appear when I writte this minimal code :
\documentclass{article} %impression recto uniquement
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot, pst-func}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=5cm, algebraic=true}%
\newcommand*\binomia[1]{
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-0.15)(7,1)%
\psBinomialC[markZeros,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!40,opacity=0.2,linecolor=cyan]{6}{#1}
\psBinomial[markZeros,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40,opacity=0.2,linecolor=red, barwidth=0.2,xlabelsep=-0.05]{6}{#1}
\psaxes[Dy=0.2,dy=0.2\psyunit]{->}(0,0)(-1,0)(7,1)
\end{pspicture}}

\binomia{0.4}\\
\binomia{0.6}


\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls, palindrome]{10}
\multiframe{50}{rA=0.02+0.02}{\binomia{\rA}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{document}

The command binomia works well, but I don't know why, the animation doesn't works.
I'm windows 11, miktek/tekmaker. 
I compile with Latex - Dvi->PS - PS->PDF 
but the PS->PDF part makes : "MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1".

Can someone help me ?

It should work with lualatex  which directly creates the pdf.

In the last loop your number rA is 1, it seems that this is not an acceptable parameter for \psBinomial you can change your code like that :
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls, palindrome]{10}
\multiframe{49}{rA=0.02+0.02}{\binomia{\rA}} % rA is from 0.02 to 0.98
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}


Wow thank u so much, i spent so much time on this for that hahaha
